# Adding locks for serializability

Tags: serialization, transactions, schedule

I am trying to enforce serializability for the following transaction schedule but my solution schedule seems to contain a logical error somewhere.

```
    T1: W(Y)
    T2: R(V) R(Y) W(Z)
    T3: W(V)
```

I would add the following S- and X-locks:

```
    T1: X(Y) W(Y) U(Y)
    T2: S(V) R(V) S(Y) R(Y) W(Z) U(Y) U(V)
    T3: X(V) W(V) U(V)
```

So the W(Y) / R(Y) and W(V) / R(V) definitely need to be locked. W(Z) does not have to. But for some reason the schedule reasoner returns a logical error.

Can anyone tell me whether I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

This solution may be helpful:

```
T1: X(Y) W(Y) U(Y)

T2: S(V) R(V) S(Y) U(V) R(Y) U(Y) W(Z)

T3: X(V) W(V) U(V)
```